# In what order were the Servants summoned for the 5th Holy Grail War?

Tags: fate-stay-night

I know that Assassin was summoned after Caster, and in most cases, Saber is the last Servant to be summoned. (The exception is in Heaven's Feel if you count True Assassin's appearance as a separate summoning).

However, I am wondering about the order of summoning of all the Servants, and if possible, the approximate times in which they were summoned.

In the visual novel, the date is shown during cutscenes, and I am quite sure that Saber was summoned on the night of 29th of February 2004, as I remember that the date changed from 29/2 into 1/3 after Shirou returned home with Saber. This can be used to approximate when the Servants were summoned.

Comment: Berserker was probably first (Gilgamesh aside). Saber is definitely last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these are explained in the visual novels of *Fate/stay night* and *Fate/hollow ataraxia*.

- First to be summoned was Berserker, two months before Saber.
- Second to be summoned was Caster, one month before Saber.
- Rider, Assassin and Lancer are summoned at around the same time, around ten days or so before Saber.
- Archer is summoned two days before Saber.

By the way, Saber was summoned during the night between February 2nd and February 3rd.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the date, i don't know why i got the end of February from  but i may have possibly confused the date switching between January and Feburary at the very beginning

Answer (score 2):

0. Gilgamesh/Archer - 1994 (Fourth Holy Grail War)
1. Heracles/Berserker - November/2003 (2 months before Day 1)
2. Medea/Caster - January/12/2004 (Been around for about a month on Day 12)
3. Cu Chulainn/Lancer - January/23/2004 (Stated in Hollow/Ataraxia)
4. Sasaki Kojirou/Assassin - January/26/2004 (Said to have been around for 20 days on Day 16)
5. Medusa/Rider - January/29/2004 (Summond 2 days before Day 1 in Heaven's Feel Manga)
6. EMIYA/Archer - February/01/2004 (Summoned before Saber)
7. Artoria Pendragon/Saber - February/03/2004 (Last servant summoned normally)
8. Hassan-i-Sabbah of the Cursed Arm/True Assassin - February/04/2004 (Summoned after Saber ONLY in Heaven's Feel)